# table group by day laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

i need to group table by day and time with laravel. i got array object where i select some info (controller):

```
public function getNotification()
{

    $message       = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('auth/main')->with(array(
        'data'     => View::make('auth/dashboard')->with([
            'message'  => $message
        ]),
        'fluid'    => true
    ));
}
```

this is my DB:

```
id/message/name/created_at
1 some text announcement 2015-03-11 10:24:05
2 some text announcement 2015-03-11 08:24:05
2 some text announcement 2015-03-10 14:24:05
4 some text announcement 2015-03-08 12:24:05
```

this is blade tmpl:

```html
<table class="table notifications">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">YESTERDAY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">8:59 am</td>
      <td class="icon"><span class="info-red"></span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>Announcement</strong>: As business grows, we all need to adapt. You've been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design. You've been growing, and receiving
        bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.You've been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.You've
        been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">8:59 am</td>
      <td class="icon"><span class="info-green"></span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>Announcement</strong>: As business grows, we all need to adapt. You've been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design. You've been growing, and receiving
        bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.You've been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.You've
        been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table notifications">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">FEBRUARY 06</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="date">8:59 am</td>
      <td class="icon"><span class="info-red"></span>
      </td>
      <td><strong>Announcement</strong>: As business grows, we all need to adapt. You've been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design. You've been growing, and receiving
        bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.You've been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.You've
        been growing, and receiving bigger amounts of orders. We've noticed the need for printing high volumes of the same kind of design.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and i need result like in my blade:

1 and 2 ID from db in one table, because they are today group,
3 id in second table, 4 id in third table

how to group table by day and how it must look like my blade tmpl with foreach maybe?

Comment: Do you want e.g. all messages from yesterday? Maybe no group needed?

Comment: i need group: if messages are on yesterday date, than in blade parse html them of one table. if massage is another date, then parse in another table, but not all messages in one table. this is must look like foreach in another foreach maybe

Comment: Yes but you can fetch the messages based on the date. To find all messages from yesterday -> ```where('created_at' > $date_yesterday)->where('created_at' <= $date_yesterday)```.

Comment: hmm, no you dont understand me. for example:

today

10:00 message
09: 00 message

yesterday
10:00 message

march 04
09:00 message

january 17

08:00 message


how it must look my tables from `grouped @messages array

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 $message  = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('created_at')->get();
```

Comment: thanks it works. my code is:

`$message = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
                ->groupBy(function($date) {
                    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('M d'); // grouping by day
                });`

how it paginate?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:

```
$message = Auth::user()->Notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
                ->groupBy(function($date) {
                    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('M d'); // grouping by day
                });
```

how it paginate?